# How to diagnose the reason why current offset was reset

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, project-reactor

Kafka(2.5.0) and Kafka consumer(io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:1.3.3).

On the production environment unexpectedly our consumer started read from beginning. What the reason of such behavior could be? How better can I diagnose the exact reason?

The consumer group wasn't changed. Nobody could reset offset by hand. auto.offset.reset = 'earliest' but we commited offsets a lot before as it happened.

Kafka cluster consist of 3 nodes.

The kafka consumer was developed using exactly once delivery semantics ( KafkaReceiver.create(...).receiveExactlyOnce(...) ). Topic configuration: cleanup.policy=compact

On the node where pod with consumer worked, there were some network issues but I don't understand how it could make the consumer reset offset.

Comment: If the offsets expire within the group (the topic logs are deleted/compacted faster than commits happen), then `auto.offset.reset` will take affect.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Does it mean that e.g. if current offset was 10, app restarted and during restart it was compaction with deleting 10th log then consumer starts from beginning considering auto.offset.reset policy.

Comment: That's right. Offset 10 doesn't exist anymore, so it would need to seek to the first available offset. For compacted topics, its generally best to re-build state of all keys, anyway

Comment: I tried to reproduce by steps:
1) create compacted topic
2)  send 40 messages with keys keyFirst1..keyFirst40.
3) launch the consumer and wait while current offset for the consumer group become equals 40
4) stop the consumer
5) send two times batch of 5000 messages with keys key1..key5000
6) wait while compaction happens
7) launch the consumer again

After the compaction I noticed that next offset after 39th was 242th. And the consumer succesfully started read messages from 242th offset.
So the assumption wasn't confirmed by this test.

Comment: Latest Kafka clients use transactional offset markers, so unless you are disabling transactions, I'm not sure simply looking at offsets is useful test